# Runnin powershell scripts on ansible playbooks (via linux ubuntu)

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am currently trying to learn a bit about Ansible.
Now during my tests I wanted to put a powershell scripts into the tasks in my playbook.
How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

just use script module

- hosts:

  tasks:

  - shell: chmod +x /path/to/script
  - script: /path/to/script